# Closing the Japplet does not end the java process

Tags: java, japplet

I have a browser based  application  which runs Japplet . I am running this application 
 on 64 bit  window machine . 
When i close the application  the java process does not close automatically . The 32 bit machine does not have this issue .
How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your comment . I was waiting for  15 sec .The process is automatically getting closed after 1 mini.

Answer (score 2):

> When I close the application the java process does not close automatically

Note that here, the 32 bit JRE typically does not exit before a minute or so passes after the last applet thread is finished.

Make sure to wait at least that long before presuming there is a (non-daemon) thread still running, or any other possible JVM/browser quirk.